# How to determine which radius is long when given points

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

If given `(center x, center y)`, `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y3)` points. 
How to determine which point is longer radius from center point easily?

I have one solution already.

**Comparing two radius value.**

```
Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x1 - center x) + Math.abs(y1 - center y))
Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x2 - center x) + Math.abs(y2 - center y))
```

But I want to know another solution if exists without using `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: Just remove the square root and compare the squared radii

Comment: Whats wrong with your way of doing it ? its pretty simple. If you are trying to apply something that looks better just implement a simple distance, point structure...

Comment: @harold I can't understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: @0014 Yes, I can do just with that approach. But calculating and comparing  occurs many time. So I'm looking for doing that without `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: Just remove the square root, it doesn't get simpler than that. It works because square root is a monotone function so the order is the same either way. By the way you do need to remove the square root off of an actual radius, currently you have like a square root of a manhattan distance..

Comment: @harold Ah!! right!! `Math.sqrt` method is not necessary in this case. Oh. Thank you very much! It can be compared with just `plus` operation.

Comment: @gentlejo You still need to square the x and y displacements, though, unless you intend to use Manhattan distance.

Comment: @Patrick87 I think that using manhattan distance is enough to compare which is longer.

Comment: That doesn't really work, it will think that any diagonal distance is longer than it actually is

Comment: Which point is farther from the origin, (2, 2) or (0, 3)? Check with some graph paper and a piece of string.

Comment: @Patrick87 Umm right. It doesn’t cover all cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you may just compare the values of:

```
(x1 - center x)^2 + (y1 - center y)^2
(x2 - center x)^2 + (y2 - center y)^2
```

To find the *actual* distance from each of your points to the center, you would have to take the square root of each. But because the square root function is monotone increasing on the positive real numbers, i.e.

```
sqrt(a) < sqrt(b) if and only if a < b,
```

you don't have to do this, and you may just compare the above sums directly.